# How to get check box values from dynamically created checkbox

Tags: android, android-checkbox

Here is the code for my check box.

```
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("checkbox")){

                String checkBoxText = dataObj.getString("checkboxname");
                checkBox = dynamicviews.CreateCheckbox(context,value,checkBoxText);

                id = R.id.gl + i + 9;
                if (j == 2) {
                    j = 0;
                    tableRow = new TableRow(context);
                    tableRow.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
                    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                }

                j++;
                tableRow.addView(checkBox);
                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        String string = checkBox.getText().toString();
                        Log.i("checkbox",string);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and below code is for creating checkbox

```
public CheckBox CreateCheckbox(Context context,String checkName,String checkBoxText){
    checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
    checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    checkBox.setTextAlignment(Gravity.CENTER);
    checkBox.setText(checkBoxText);
    checkBox.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_rdbtn);
    checkBox.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
    checkBox.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
    return checkBox;
}
```

and problem is am getting the value of last created checkbox for each one.

Comment: You could try storing the checkbox instances in an `ArrayList<CheckBox>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        String string = buttonView.getText().toString();
                        Log.i("checkbox",string);


                    }
                });
```

i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `checkBoxobject` to the `tableRow` **BEFORE** you set its `setOnCheckedChangeListener` - so it will only work for the last `checkBox` you've created.

To solve this, you simply need to do set the setOnCheckedChangeListener first, and then call the `tableRow.addView(checkBox)` - see the code below:

```
//first, set the setOnCheckedChangeListener on this checkBox,
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)     
    {   String string = buttonView.getText().toString();
       Log.i("checkbox",string);
    }
});
//only now do you add the view
tableRow.addView(checkBox);
```

Give it a try, I hope it helps.

Comment: Noted. Instead of `checkBox.getText()`, it should be `buttonView.getText()` - the `onCheckedChanged` method passes the `checkBox` view (`CompoundButton`) whose checked state has changed. I updated the code accordingly and it should work. The biggest issue was adding the `checkBoxobject` before setting the listener.